# Should I have a Joint account with spouse?

Tags: marriage, joint-account

We have been married for almost 10 years, and have a stable, happy relationship. Both of us were working and living independently before getting married, and we continued the arrangement after marriage. In other words, we do not have a joint account for household expenses. We (more or less) have a division of household expenses, and I can see from credit reports that we are current on everything. I do not have a problem with how my spouse spends money and afaik, the feeling is mutual. I do not have any access to my spouse's money and vice-versa.

**Is there any compelling reason to have a joint account for household expenses?** We are in the US, if that matters.

If our relationship turns terrible, I think I will be OK to divorce without any financial entanglements.

Comment: I really like Ben's link and answer.  The wife and I do exactly as he says.  Yes there are very compelling reasons to have only joint accounts.